# docker compose wont populate env variables into script

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to use some environment variable inside my docker compose file:

```yaml
backend:
    container_name: backend
    build:
        context: ./docker
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.api-dev
        args:
            - API_NAME=backend
    env_file:
        - ./apps/backend/envs/.env.development
        - ./docker/envs/.env.development
    ports:
        - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    restart: always
    depends_on:
        - mongo_replica_1
        - mongo_replica_2
        - mongo_replica_3
    networks:
        - mongo_network
```

As you can see I provide `env_file`. There are 2 files. One of them has `PORT` configured. But when I run the `docker-compose up` I get a warning: `WARN[0000] The "PORT" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.`

So where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part:

```
    env_file:
        - ./apps/backend/envs/.env.development
        - ./docker/envs/.env.development
```

defines environment variables for the RUNNING service/container.

The port that you want to substitute is read by docker-compose at config time (when it interprets the docker-compose.yml and tries to understand what you need).

For that you need a `.env` next to the docker-compose.yml and define the PORT in the `.env`. Or if your environment file has a different name:

```
docker-compose --env-file .env.development up
```